# How to restart dlib's correlation tracker

Tags: python, tracking, dlib

I'm using dlib's correaltion tracker and would like to restart it on some que. When 
I pass `None` as the `image` it crashes. How can I tell the tracker a new video is starting?
I'm using multiple thread and would not like to open a new tracker every time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the correlation_tracker's start_track() member function.